# Can i add property id from GA4 into branchIO instead of tracking id?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, branch.io, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

I am trying to feed branchIO campaign information to google analytics4.
BranchIo is requesting me add tracking id which is of the format UA-xxxxxxx-x , but this kind of id is not available in google analytics 4. Is it ok to use property id instead.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics UA and GA4 are two completely different systems.

Universal analytics accounts have UA Ids.    GA4 Have measurment ids

No you can not.   You are using the code for UA it will only work with UA accounts.

The measurement protocol used to send data to these different systems is also different. There for the code needed to send to that system should also be different

You appear to be trying to use a tracker designed to send data to UA accounts. not GA4 accounts.

No it is not okay to send the property id instead. You sould send the UA id or find the code for that system that would work with GA4 which will take a